# Border on round box not shown on Android / Chrome

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, browser

check out this Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aweEZN

HTML:

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border: 10px solid #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

On desktop browsers everything works as expected, but on my phone the border around the box is not shown (I guess it's a browser bug). I'm using Android 6.0.1 and Chrome Version 59.0.3071.125.

Can someone help me with a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers don't support certain CSS3 properties. Try separating them into their individual properties, like this:

CSS:

```
.circle {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: That makes no difference. Chrome for Android supports all of the above properties.